# Using NDSolve on wave PDE on string, when solution given at 2 different times instead of initial velocity?

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, finite-element-method

This is a PDE taken from a Maple document. Mathematica DSolve currently unable to solve it.

I wanted to verify Maple solution using NDSolve. This is string of length 1, fixed on the left, and free to move on the right. Given an initial position and let go.

Here is the specs of the PDE

Solve for $0<x<1, t>0$ the wave PDE
$$
   -u_{tt} + u(x,t)=  u_{xx} + 2 e^{-t} \left( x - \frac{1}{2} x^2 + \frac{1}{2} t - 1 \right)
$$

With boundary condition

\begin{align*}
  u(0,t) &= 0 \\
  \frac{\partial u(1,t)}{\partial x} &= 0
\end{align*}

And initial conditions

\begin{align*}
 u(x,0) &= x^2-2 x \\
 u(x,1)&= u\left(x,\frac{1}{2}\right) + e^{-1} \left( \frac{1}{2} x^2-x\right) - \left( \frac{3}{4} x^2- \frac{3}{2}x \right) e^{\frac{-1}{2}}
\end{align*}

The tricky part in this, is that no initial velocity is given. But only initial position at $t=0$, and then a relation on the solution at 2 different times is give instead.

`NDSolve` complain with that dreaded error

> Boundary condition  is not specified on a single edge  of the boundary
>   of the computational domain.

And I do not know how to get rid of it. Here is the code

```
ClearAll[u, x, t];
pde = -D[u[x, t], {t, 2}] + u[x, t] == 
           D[u[x, t], {x, 2}] + 2*Exp[-t]*(x - (1/2)*x^2 + (1/2)*t - 1);

bc = {u[0, t] == 0, Derivative[1, 0][u][1, t] == 0};

ic = {u[x, 0] == x^2 - 2*x, 
    u[x, 1] == u[x, 1/2] + ((1/2)*x^2 - x)*Exp[-1] - ((3*x^2)/4 - (3/2)*x)* Exp[-2^(-1)]};

sol = NDSolve[{pde, ic, bc}, u, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

Here is the Maple code and the analytical solution it gives

```
pde := -diff(u(x, t), t, t) + u(x, t) = 
       diff(u(x, t), x, x)+ 2*exp(-t)*(x-(1/2)*x^2+(1/2)*t-1);
ic  := u(x, 0) = x^2-2*x, 
       u(x, 1) = u(x, 1/2)+((1/2)*x^2-x)*exp(-1)-(3/4*(x^2)-3/2*x)*exp(-1/2);
bc  := u(0, t) = 0, eval(diff(u(x, t), x), {x = 1}) = 0;
pdsolve([pde, ic, bc],u(x,t))
```

$$
u(x,t) = -\frac{e^{-t}}{2}  (x^2-2 x) (t-2)
$$

Here is animation of Maple solution, which I wanted to verify

```
mapleSol[x_, t_] := -(Exp[-t]/2) (x^2 - 2 x) (t - 2)
Manipulate[
 Plot[mapleSol[x, t], {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {-1, .1}}],
 {{t, 0, "time"}, 0, 10, .1}
 ]
```

[image]

Any suggestion how to get rid of the error from NDSolve?

Using V 12 on windows 10.  ps. I solved this by hand also, but can't get Maple solution, and my solution looks wrong. I still need to find out why.

Comment: What Maple delivers here is simply excellent!

Comment: @rmw yes. Nice solution. I struggled to find out how to get same solution analytically for few hrs and could not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have time to make a solid answer, but this seems to work :

```
pde = -D[u[x, t], {t, 2}] + u[x, t] == 
   D[u[x, t], {x, 2}] + 2*Exp[-t]*(x - (1/2)*x^2 + (1/2)*t - 1) + 
    NeumannValue[0, x == 1];

bc = {u[0, t] == 0};

ic = {u[x, 0] == x^2 - 2*x
   , PeriodicBoundaryCondition[
    u[x, t] - (((1/2)*x^2 - x)*Exp[-1] - ((3*x^2)/4 - (3/2)*x)*
        Exp[-2^(-1)])
    , t == 1 && 0 < x < 1
    , Function[xy, xy - {0, 1/2}]]};

U = NDSolveValue[{pde, ic, bc}, u, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}];
Plot3D[U[x, t], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {x, t, u}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[{
  U[x, 0]
  , U[x, 1/2]
  , U[x, 1]
  , U[x, 1/2] + ((1/2)*x^2 - x)*Exp[-1] - ((3*x^2)/4 - (3/2)*x)*
    Exp[-2^(-1)]}, {x, 0, 1}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Directive[Blue, AbsoluteThickness[7]], 
   Directive[Black, Dashed, AbsoluteThickness[3]]}, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

Here is the error :

```
Plot3D[Evaluate[-D[U[x, t], {t, 2}] + 
   U[x, t] - (D[U[x, t], {x, 2}] + 
     2*Exp[-t]*(x - (1/2)*x^2 + (1/2)*t - 1))], {t, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

The method automaticaly chosen by `NDSolve` is `Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement"}}` (as opposed to  `Method] -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", femopts}}}`)  . This is the reason why one can impose boundaries condition on the variable "time".

Note also that the term "PeriodicBoundaryCondition" is a little bit misleading because the source of the "boundary condition" does not need to be a boundary.

Comment: What a tricky solution! Thanks. That means in a rectangular region it is possible to define coupled boundary conditions which aren't periodic at all. For example `PeriodicBoundaryCondition[u[x, t] - f[x,t] , t == 1 && 0 < x < 1 , Function[xy, xy - {x0, t0}]]` is somthing like `u[x,1]+f[x,1]==u[x-x0,1-t0]+f[ x-x0,t-t0]`???

Comment: Nice answer (+1). @UlrichNeumann, you should have a look at the ref page of `PeriodicBoundaryCondition` That explains a bit better what PBC does and has  examples.

Comment: @user21 Thank you for your hint, I tried to understand the documentation. Do you think my conclusion (see comment) is ok?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann, I think that is correct but I hesitate a bit because I have not tried it.

Comment: @user21 Thanks, I also try to build an example...

Answer (score 1):

Just an extended comment:

If you change the second bc to `NeumannValue` Mathematica is able to solve the modified initial value problem `u[x, 1] ==(* u[x,1/2]+*) ((1/2)*x^2 - x)*Exp[-1] - ((3*x^2)/4 - (3/2)*x)*Exp[-2^(-1)]`

```
pde = -D[u[x, t], {t, 2}] + u[x, t] ==D[u[x, t], {x, 2}] + 2*Exp[-t]*(x - (1/2)*x^2 +(1/2)*t - 1) +NeumannValue[0, x == 1];

bc = {u[0, t] == 0};

ic = {u[x, 0] == x^2 - 2*x, 
u[x, 1] ==(* u[x,1/2]+*) ((1/2)*x^2 - x)*Exp[-1] - ((3*x^2)/4 - (3/2)*x)*Exp[-2^(-1)]};

U = NDSolveValue[{pde, ic, bc}, u, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1} ];
Plot3D[U[x, t], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {x, t, u}]
```

[image]

The coupling `u[x,1],u[x,1/2]` still remains unsolved!