# Wave equation: Understanding PeriodicBoundaryCondition

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, boundary-conditions

Inspired by the interesting question [202542](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/202542/using-ndsolve-on-wave-pde-on-string-when-solution-given-at-2-different-times-in/202570?noredirect=1#comment523476_202570) I try to solve the wave equation  with coupled boundary conditions

`u[x,t==1 ]==u[x,t==x/2]`

I tried

`PeriodicBoundaryCondition[u[x, t],t == 1 && 0 < x < 1,Function[xy, xy - {0, 1- xy[[1]]/2}]]`

with x-dependent time shift

```
pde = D[u[x, t], {t, 2}] ==D[u[x, t], {x, 2}] + NeumannValue[0, x == 1];
bc = {u[0, t] == 0};
ic = {u[x, 0] == x^2 - 2*x};
pbc = {PeriodicBoundaryCondition[u[x, t],t == 1  && 0 < x < 1,Function[xy, xy - {0, 1 - xy[[1]]/2}]]}

U = NDSolveValue[{ pde, ic, bc, pbc}, u, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

But the solution doesn't fullfill the required `u[x,t==1 ]==u[x,t==x/2]`

```
Plot[U[x, 1] - U[x, x/2], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Any idea what's going wrong here?

In the next step I would like to solve the boundary conditions `u[x,t==1-x/2 ]==u[x,t==x/2]` but NDSolve doesn't find a solution.

Thanks!

Comment: This may just be an issue with the order of the `InterpolatingFunction` and how it's plotted.  Have you tried using `InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy` to see what the actual discrete grid values of the function are?

Comment: @Michael Seifert Thanks, the boundary condition seems to be fullfilled only pointwise. I believe NDSolve uses `Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement"}}` but I don't know how to force "smooth" finite elements, because the documentation concerning "PDEDiscretization" is rare.

Comment: It appears that you can control the properties of the mesh via `Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement",  "MeshOptions" -> { (* list of options *)}}}]`.  This along with the tutorial [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/ElementMeshCreation.html) might get you somewhere.  Alternately, you could try forcing `"PDEDiscretization" -> "TensorProductGrid"`, since your domain is fairly simple (though who knows if it'll work for the antiperiodic BCs you want to do next.)  I'd play around with this more if I have time over the next few days.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert "TensorPoructGrid" is no alternative because NDSolve doesn't run in this case. I tried succesfully `"MeshOptions"->{"MaxCellMeasure" -> .0004}`. Thanks again for your effort, I'm curious about your next messages concerning antiperiodic BC.

Comment: Note that for this to be a wave equation you'd need to specify a derivative of the initial condition. Without it this is solved as a pure spatial PDE. Look at `U["ElementMesh"]

Comment: @user21 Thanks, I agree. But independent of the b.c. 
 it still remains a wave equation with very special restrictions. Until now there was only a solution using `PeriodicBoundaryCondititons`. Perhaps one can formulate a `ConditionalExpression` ?

Comment: Even if you remove the PBC `NDSolve` does not solve this as a time dependent PDE. What is in your formulation the temporal derivative (derivative of IC) on the boundary?

Comment: There is no temporal derivative of ic.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to improve the first result in my question I found some interesting points:

**First**

Include `x==1`inside the boundary condition

```
pbc = {PeriodicBoundaryCondition[u[x, t],t == 1  && 0 < x <= 1,Function[xy, xy - {0, 1 - xy[[1]]/2}]]
```

**Second**

Choose "<< NDSolve`FEM`" and a predefined mesh as simple as possible(triangle elements not quad!)

```
<< NDSolve`FEM`
netz = ToElementMesh[ Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}],"MeshElementType" -> TriangleElement]
```

**=>Improved solution**

```
U = NDSolveValue[{ pde, ic, bc, pbc}, u, Element[{x, t}, netz]];
Plot[{ U[x, 1] - U[x, x/2]}, {x, 0, 1},AxesLabel -> {t, " U[x,1]-U[x,x/2]"},PlotLabel -> "(a)periodic boundary condition" ]
```

[image]

**interim conclusion:**

It's worth to use a predefined mesh
The simple triangle mesh gives "better" results than quad mesh.

Unfortunately the obvious generalization `pbc = {PeriodicBoundaryCondition[u[x, t],t == 1 - x/2  && 0 < x < 1,Function[xy, xy - {0, 1 -xy[[1]] }]]};` to realize the condition `u[x,t==1-x/2 ]==u[x,t==x/2]` still doesn't work...