# Cross coupling in DirichletCondition not supported -- conflict with documentation?

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

Mathematica 12.0.0.0 happily solves the trivial coupled differential system as follows:

`NDSolve[{D[u[x], x] == 1, D[v[x], x] == 1, 
  DirichletCondition[v[x] == 1, x == 0], 
  DirichletCondition[u[x] == 0, x == 0]}, {u, v}, {x, 0, 1}]`

but complains when given differently stated (but equivalent) boundary conditions:

`NDSolve[{D[u[x], x] == 1, D[v[x], x] == 1, 
  DirichletCondition[v[x] - u[x] == 1, x == 0], 
  DirichletCondition[v[x] + u[x] == 1, x == 0]}, {u, v}, {x, 0, 1}]`

> **NDSolve::fembdcc** "Cross-coupling of dependent variables in DirichletCondition ... is not supported in this version"

The error message seems clear -- it does not like when `u` and `v` simultaneously appear in a Dirichlet condition.  But why not?  Indeed, the documentation of `DirichletCondition` seems to imply that a general equation is supported:

> `DirichletCondition[beqn,pred]`:  "In general, the boundary equation `beqn` needs to be affine linear in the dependent variables, i.e. `h1 u1+ … = r`, where `hi` and `r` can depend on any of the independent variables `{x1,x2,…}`."

[DirichletCondition---Documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DirichletCondition.html)

Answer (score 1):

Without `DirichletCondition` NDSolve evaluates the solution:

```
{U, V} = NDSolveValue[{D[u[x], x] == 1, D[v[x], x] == 1,v[0] - u[0] == 1 , v[0] + u[0] == 1 }, {u, v}, {x, 0, 1}]
{V[0] + U[0 ], V[0] - U[0 ]} 
(* {1,1} *)
```

Unfortunately using only one DirichletCondition `DirichletCondition[v[x] - u[x] == 1 && v[x] + u[x], x == 0]` doesn't work.

Comment: Curious...  thanks for this workaround.  I think it may only work for ODEs.  I tried the same thing with a PDE (with two independent variables), and unfortunately got the error again.  With a PDE, Mathematica seems to generate a `DirichletCondition` internally.  So it still seems useful to understand the behavior with `DirichletCondition`

Comment: For PDE you might use `PeriodicBoundaries` instead of coupled `DirichletConditions`: See  [202645](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/202645/wave-equation-understanding-periodicboundarycondition?noredirect=1#comment524308_202645) and [202542](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/202542/using-ndsolve-on-wave-pde-on-string-when-solution-given-at-2-different-times-in/202570?noredirect=1#comment523476_202570)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.  I looked at the examples you sent, but although I can see how this method could allow you to "couple" a single dependent variable to itself (at different values of the independent variables) I'm not sure I see how `PeriodicBoundaryCondition` can be used to impose a Dirichlet condition, at least not in a straightforward manner.

Comment: Sorry für my misleading Suggestion. I think actual MMA can solve only explicit DirichletConditions.

Comment: Thanks nevertheless Ulrich!