# Longitudinal Bar Vibration & Boundary Condition Problems

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, finite-element-method, boundary-conditions

I am trying to solve the PDE for longitudinal vibrations in a bar (as shown for example at [Youtube Longitudinal Bar Vibration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?reload=9&v=dpsS3H0RWG8)).  My challenge is the application I am trying to solve has these boundary conditions:

Left(x=0) end free; Right end(x=len) forced sinusoidal displacement.

```
ClearAll[len, ρ, Y, c, x, t, tmax, z]
len = 1; (*meter *)
tmax = 5;
ρ = 7860; (*kg/m^3 for steel*)
Y = 199*^9; (*Newtons/m^2*)
c = Sqrt[Y/ρ];

nsol11 = NDSolve[Derivative[0, 2][z][x, t] == NeumannValue[0, x == 0] + 
    (ρ*Derivative[2, 0][z][x, t])/Y,
    z[len, t] == 0.005*Sin[1*t]}, z[x, t], {x, 0, len}, {t, 0, tmax},
    Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement"}}]
fnnsol11[x_, t_] = nsol11[[1, 1, 2]];

Plot3D[fnnsol11[x, t], {x, 0, len}, {t, 0, tmax}, 
 PlotLabels -> Automatic, AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All,  
 PlotLabel -> "Displacement vs. Time", 
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
 PlotPoints -> 150]
```

The problem I have is it solves, but the "free" left end is not oscillating like the forced displacement right end.  With the input values used (a 1m long steel bar) the input and output should very closely match in phase and magnitude. My understanding is applying the free boundary condition as a NeumannValue[] was the proper way to do it as learned from this question.[NDsolve related problem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/202542/using-ndsolve-on-wave-pde-on-string-when-solution-given-at-2-different-times-in)

In summary, my question is how can I properly apply a free and forced displacement boundary condition to the PDE for a longitudinal vibration in a rod?

Thank You

Comment: I believe that the ODE should be `NDSolve[Derivative[0, 2][z][x, t] ==  c^2 Derivative[2, 0][z][x, t]`.  As written in the question, `c^2` is replaced by `c^-2`.  By the way, your usage of the `Newton` condition is fine.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Thank you @bbgodfrey for the help.  You absolutely solved my problem.  Fantastic!

Comment: Your `NDSolve` FEM options does not do what you think it does. Have a look at the [FiniteElementOptions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementOptions.html) tutorial to learn more.

Comment: I'll read up for sure and thanks for the reference, but can you be more specific to help point me in the right direction?  As a new user it's a bit like drinking from a firehose. 
 Thank you.